# Shell script: find cannot deal with folder in quotation marks

Tags: bash, shell

I am facing a problem with the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

searchPattern=".*\/.*\.abc|.*\/.*\.xyz|.*\/.*\.[0-9]{3}"
subFolders=$(find -E * -type d -regex ".*201[0-4][0-1][0-9].*|.*20150[1-6].*" -maxdepth 0 | sed 's/.*/"&"/')

echo "subFolders: $subFolders"

# iterate through subfolders
for thisFolder in $subFolders
do
  echo "The current subfolder is: $thisFolder"

  find -E $thisFolder -type f -iregex $searchPattern -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 7z a -mx=9 -uz1 -x!.DS_Store ${thisFolder}/${thisFolder}_data.7z
done
```

The idea behind it is to archive filetypes with the ending .abc, .xyz and .000-.999 in one 7z archive per subfolder. However, I can't manage to deal with folders including spaces. When I run the script as shown above I always get the following error:

```
find: "20130117_test": No such file or directory
```

If I run the script with the line

```
subFolders=$(find -E * -type d -regex ".*201[0-4][0-1][0-9].*|.*20150[1-6].*" -maxdepth 0 | sed 's/.*/"&"/')
```

changed to

```
subFolders=$(find -E * -type d -regex ".*201[0-4][0-1][0-9].*|.*20150[1-6].*" -maxdepth 0)
```

the script works like charm, but of course not for folders containing space.

Strangely enough, when I execute the following line directly in shell, it works as expected:

```
find -E "20130117_test" -type f -iregex ".*\/.*\.abc|.*\/.*\.xyz|.*\/.*\.[0-9]{3}" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 7z a -mx=9 -uz1 -x!.DS_Store "20130117_test"/"20130117_test"_data.7z
```

I know the issue is somehow related to the storing of a list of folders (in quotes) in the subFolders variable, but I simply cannot find a way to make it work properly.

I hope someone more advanced in shell can help me out here.

Comment: The standard way to loop on the output of (GNU) `find` is: `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do ...something with "$filename"...; done < <(find .... -print0)`. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (I think it's a good idea if you read that page, and maybe read all the information available on this site!).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks for the advice! It took me quite some studying, but I managed to get it working (see my answer below)

Comment: Literal quotes (quotes in the data your script processes) cannot substitute for syntactic quotes (quotes in the script itself). See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not use `find` in an attempt to generate a list of file names. You especially cannot build a quoted list the way you are attempting; there is a difference between quotes *in* a parameter value and quotes *around* a parameter expansion. Here, especially, you can just use simple patterns:

```
shopt -s nullglob

subFolders=(
  *201[0-4][0-1][0-9]*
  *20150[1-6]*
)
for thisFolder in "${subFolders[@]}"; do
  echo "The current subfolder is: $thisFolder"
  to_archive=(
    */*.abc
    */*.xyz
    */*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]
  )
  7z a -mx9 -uz1 -x!.DS_Store "$thisFolder/$thisFolder_data.7z" "${to_archive[@]}"
done
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However if I simply try the following: `subFolders=( *201[0-4][0-1][0-9]* *20150[1-6]* ); for thisFolder in "${subFolders[@]}"; do; echo "The current subfolder is: $thisFolder"; done`, I still don't deal well with spaces, since I get `The current subfolder is: 20130208_test The current subfolder is: 20130208_test with spaces` and furthermore I get `The current subfolder is: *20150[1-6]*`. Do you have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: That looks like it is dealing with spaces exactly as it should. As for the second problem, there aren't any folders matching `*20150[1-6]*`; use `shopt -s nullglob` so that non-matching patterns are ignored instead of used as literal strings.

Comment: the `shopt -s nullglob`option makes sense, because in my test folder I actually don't have subfolders beginning with something like `*20150[1-6]*`at the moment. Also, spaces are dealt with nicely now. I just noticed that from earlier tests there was a wrong folder created ("20130208_test" shouldn't exist, but only "20130208_test with spaces"). However, at the moment not only directories, but also files are listed in "subFolders". How can I only include folders in subFolders?

Answer (score 0):

Combining the input from gniourf_gniourf and chepner I was able to produce the following code, which does exactly what I want.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

find -E "$PWD" -type d -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*201[0-5][0-1][0-9].*" -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" thisFolder ; do
  echo "The current folder is: $thisFolder"
  to_archive=( "$thisFolder"/*.[Aa][Bb][Cc] "$thisFolder"/*.[Xx][Yy][Zz] "$thisFolder"/*.[0-9][0-9][0-9] )

  if [ ${#to_archive[@]} != 0 ]
  then
    7z a -mx=9 -uz1 -x!.DS_Store "$thisFolder"/"${thisFolder##*/}"_data.7z "${to_archive[@]}" && rm "${to_archive[@]}"
  fi
done
```

`shopt -s nullglob` leads to ignorance towards non-matching characters

`find...` searches for directories matching the regex pattern and streams each matching folder to the while loop using the null separator.

inside the while loop I can safely quote the `$thisFolder` variable expansion and therefore deal with possible spaces.

using absolute paths instead of relative paths instructs 7z to create no folders inside the archive